# Multiple outputs to a textbox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Background:

I am writing a C# form program with MSVS 2010. The form has 2 textboxes: textBox1 (input, single line) and textBox2 (output, multiple lines).

I want to enter a string in textBox1 and when a condition is met it prints some text to textBox2. I want to be able to enter multiple inputs and print output to textBox2 and not erase the previous output.

Questions:

1. My question is can this be done?
2. If not can you use multiple text boxes and move the output to the next higher value text box?

Comment: wpf? winforms? asp.net? silverlight? (etc)

Comment: I am new to C# also. I am assuming .net

Comment: Are you new to frameworks?!?!?!?!

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI Yes I am. The only language I had an actual class on is C. I have had to teach myself a little of C++ and C# and having problems as I go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is keep appending to the text property.

```
string output = "Hi!";
outputBox.Text += output + Environment.NewLine;
```

This is, of course, after you've given your textbox a more meaningful name than `textBox2`

Bonus: You can also prepend to the text if you prever new output to appear at the top:

```
outputBox.Text = output + Environment.NewLine + outputBox.Text;
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. I tested it in my simple program and worked like a dream. Next step is to figure out how to clear the input textbox after the output is displayed.

Comment: @ajaustin12: ...set the Text to the empty string? It's just a string property, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I apologize I did not tell everyone I am new at C#. So I am unsure how to do that. If you have a link that explains it that would be great.

Comment: @ajaustin12: Do you know how to assign a value to a variable? Do you know how to assign a value to a property of an object...?

Comment: I am having difficulties with declaring variables at the moment. MSVS is not liking how I am declaring variables. No to your 2nd part.

Comment: I did a google search on how to clear a textbox and came up with this

`textBox1.Text=""`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done.  Just append the text from textBox1 to the existing text in textBox2.  You can set up some kind of event handler to check if the condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that can be done. You just need to concatenate the existing text in textBox2 with the new text you want to add.

Here is a very simple way to do this:

```
textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + "new text"
```

Answer (score 1):

sure, all can be done:

1)  *"enter a string in textBox1 and when a condition is met "*

this can be done in several ways, if condition is user derived event (such as key press) this can be done using [events](http://www.csharp-station.com/Articles/EventHandlingInCSharp.aspx).
if condition is checked separably by program then simple

```
if(condition){
  textBox1.Text += output;
}
```

will suffice.

---

2) *"I want to be able to enter multiple inputs"*

multiple inputs simply means reading more textboxes

---

3) *"print output to textBox2 and not erase the previous output."*

this can be done as follows:

```
// append at end
textBox1.Text += output;
// append at start
 textBox1.Text = output + textBox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use an `ItemsControl` to display each line, then you just add the new line to the `List` source.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx